# Is there any advantage using generic type which implements interface over direct interface usage?

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, interfaces, generics

When I was looking [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273214/injecting-data-processing-logic-into-class) question, a question comes my mind.

Think about using an interface like :

```cs
public interface ICommandProcessor<T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Process(T command);
}
```

When you think about just interfaces, is there any advantage over direct using? Like :

```cs
public interface ICommandProcessor
{
    void Process(ICommand command);
}
```

**Edit:**

@Olivier's answer hits a good point.

> It is an advantage if you want to create a command processor for **a specialized command type**

If specialized command type is needed, it is good. But I am not sure to force all command classes to use generics because of maybe they would need specialized command type. So, when think both things :

```cs
public interface ICommandProcessor<in T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Process(T command);
}

public interface ICommandProcessor : ICommandProcessor<ICommand>
{

}

public class SampleClass : ICommandProcessor
{
    public void Process(ICommand command)
    {
        //..
    }
}

public class AnotherSampleClass : ICommandProcessor<IAnotherCommand>
{
    public void Process(IAnotherCommand command)
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

Can we say it is the best design for `ICommandProcessor`? 
By this way, classes can implement `ICommandProcessor` or `ICommandProcessor<T>` if needs to create special one, I think.

Comment: The advantages are the same as those you get by using generic typing elsewhere (i.e. *not* in an interface).  The interface has its own benefits, but those benefits are independent from the ones you obtain from generic typing.

Comment: So the question is not "why use generics in interfaces," it's [why use generics.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Comment: Anyway, the advantage of your first code sample over your second one is that `T` is constrained to `ICommand` at compile time, so if you get your concrete types wrong, you won't have to wait until your program blows up unexpectedly at run time to find that out.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Isn't it same as second usage? Concrete types should implements `ICommand`.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), which says: *"Constraints inform the compiler about the capabilities a type argument must have. Without any constraints, the type argument could be any type. The compiler can only assume the members of System.Object, which is the ultimate base class for any .NET type."*

Comment: And [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#why-use-constraints), which says: *"By constraining the type parameter, you increase the number of allowable operations and method calls to those supported by the constraining type and all types in its inheritance hierarchy. When you design generic classes or methods, if you will be performing any operation on the generic members beyond simple assignment or calling any methods not supported by System.Object, you will have to apply constraints to the type parameter..."*

Comment: ... *"For example, the base class constraint tells the compiler that only objects of this type or derived from this type will be used as type arguments. Once the compiler has this guarantee, it can allow methods of that type to be called in the generic class. "*

Comment: In other words, the generic types and constraints actually *increase* your options, not decrease them, while also guaranteeing type safety at compile time.

Comment: As to generic interfaces themselves, they are used to avoid boxing and unboxing operations on primitive types, which can cause performance problems.  See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-interfaces).

Comment: @RobertHarvey It would be great to see all your comment as an answer with demonstrated example. Anyway thank you for all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an advantage if you want to create a command processor for a specialized command type. E.g. you have an interface

```
public interface IUndoableCommand : ICommand
{
    void Undo();
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
public class UndoableCommandProcessor : ICommandProcessor<IUndoableCommand>
{
    public void Process(IUndoableCommand command)
    {
        //TODO: Execute command. Push command to undo stack.
    }
}
```

`UndoableCommandProcessor.Process()` will not accept a simple `ICommand`.

---

The generic variant allows you to create specialized command processors restricted to process only specialized commands.

The non-generic variant allows you to create specialized commands and pass them to the processor, but the command processor must always be able to process the general `ICommand`.

---

A disadvantage of generic types is, that they are not assignment compatible when specialized with different generic type parameters. So `T<A>` and `T<B>` are not assignment compatible, even if `A` and `B` are. (Exception, see: [Creating Variant Generic Interfaces (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces)).

Therefore, it is often useful for generic types to have a non-generic base type.

```
public interface ICommandProcessor
{
    void Process(ICommand command);
}

public interface ICommandProcessor<T> : ICommandProcessor
    where T : ICommand
{
    void Process(T command);
}
```

*So, this is the exact contrary of your approach* `public interface ICommandProcessor : ICommandProcessor<ICommand>`.

An implementation would hide the non-generic `Process` method by implementing it explicitly. This makes it accessible only when called directly through the `ICommandProcessor` interface.

If we have

```
public interface ICommand { }
public interface ICommandA : ICommand { }
public interface ICommandB : ICommand { }
```

Then we can create a specialized implementation like this:

```
public class CommandProcessorA : ICommandProcessor<ICommandA>
{
    void ICommandProcessor.Process(ICommand command) // Explicit implementation
    {
    }

    public void Process(ICommandA command) // Implicit implementation
    {
    }
}
```

We declare `public class CommandProcessorB : ICommandProcessor<ICommandB>` the same way. Now we can store different command processors like this

```
var processors = new List<ICommandProcessor> {
    new CommandProcessorA(),
    new CommandProcessorB()
};
```

This does not work:

```
// DOES NOT COMPILE!
var processors = new List<ICommandProcessor<ICommand>> {
    new CommandProcessorA(),
    new CommandProcessorB()
};
```

We get

> **Error    CS1950**    The best overloaded Add method 'List<ICommandProcessor<ICommand>>.Add(ICommandProcessor<ICommand>)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments  ...

Answer (score 0):

Building further on Olivers answer. Its also alot easier to get a factory going with a generic interface version. You just do

```
public class CommandRunner
{
   public CommandRunner(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
   {
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }

   public void Execute<TCOmmand>(TCommand cmd) where TCommand : ICommand
   {
      _serviceProvider.GetService<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>().Execute(cmd);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only tell what the best design is after you established your usage scenario.

ICommandProcessor would work with any command whereas ICommandProcessor`<T>` would only work with a specific type of command. The first will give you more flexibility (it is more generic than the generic interface, go figure). The latter gives you stronger type safety.

What is more important to your application? Do you want to toss around commands that your main logic does not need to know the details about? Or do you discriminate between command types in your main logic?

It won't hurt to declare both interfaces. After all, it only starts to matter once a class implements either. And you can always implement both but that may not be helpful to the user of your class. Choosing one sends a message about the intended usage scenario. That is what you should consider: what is a command to me (or to my application). The choice between the two interfaces should follow.